# Unicode Error when trying to use Command Prompt with USB Flash drive or SD Card

Tags: usb, cmd.exe, sd-card, unicode, utf-8

I have problems when trying to use unicode characters like Russian characters (Cyrillic) on the Command Prompt (CMD). This problem only happens when I am on USB Flash drive or SD Card, which use FAT32. I use Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bits.

For instance, when I am on F:\ and try to open "F:\Что-то.docx" the error I get is:

"No mapping for the unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page."

However, when I open files with latin characters "Hello.docx" works ok. When I use NTFS Hard Drive (C,D) works ok without errors too, so it seems that it only happens when using external drivers.

I have also try CHCP 65001 before starting with other lines but doesn't help.

[The error I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUi1h.jpg)

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Robert: It does, LFNs in FAT are stored as UTF-16.

Comment: @Robert Exist any solution for that?

Comment: Use the short 8.3 version of the file name which can be shown using `dir /x`.

Comment: @Jay Thank you, "dir /x" name worked on CMD. 

Only when opening BAT files with Unicode characters on the file name does not work. 
Is there a way to prevent the error when directly opening Bat files?

Comment: @lmeza-28: In batch file, open it like this: `for %A in ("f:\Что-то.docx") do "%~sA"`

Comment: @lmeza-28: In batch file, open it like this: `for %A in ("f:\Что-то.docx") do "%~sA"`